# Реализация API в вебсервере для возврата разных типов данных на примере flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, ip

Для примера пусть сервер **возвращает IP клиента**

Сделал возврат как [html](/questions/tagged/html), как сделать возврат в [json](/questions/tagged/json) и [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)?

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return request.remote_addr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=5000
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы `flask` вернул данные в `json` достаточно, например, вернуть словарь, пусть это будет `{'ip': request.remote_addr}`

А чтобы `flask` вернул как `xml` нужно вернуть как строку/байты и указать тип, например, `text/xml`, чтобы клиент имел представление о типе данных от сервера. Для этого нужно вернуть объект [Response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Response).
Строку `xml` можно и самостоятельно сгенерировать (типа `<ip>127.0.0.1</ip>`), но я предпочту сделать через библиотеку, например, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Пример:

```
import logging
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from flask import Flask, request, Response


app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return request.remote_addr


@app.route('/json')
def get_json():
    return {
        'ip': request.remote_addr,
    }


@app.route('/xml')
def get_xml():
    root = ET.Element('ip')
    root.text = request.remote_addr
    xml_bytes = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
    return Response(xml_bytes, mimetype='text/xml')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=5000
    )
```

#### Результат

Пусть, ip будет 10.10.10.10), обратите внимание на заголовок ответа `Content-Type`:

- **http://10.10.10.10:5000/** (`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`):

  ```
  10.7.8.31
  ```
- **http://10.10.10.10:5000/xml** (`Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`):

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <ip>10.7.8.31</ip>
  ```
- **http://10.10.10.10:5000/json** (`Content-Type: application/json`):

  ```
  {"ip":"10.7.8.31"}
  ```